# Show that if the integral of function with compact support on straight line is zero, then $f$ is zero almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I want to prove that that given $f:R^2 \rightarrow R$ which is continuous with compact support s.t the integral of $f$ for every straight line $l$ is zero ($\int f(l(t))\mathrm{d}t=0$) then $f$ is almost everywhere $0.$

Well I know how to proof it in case that $l = 1_{B(x,r)}$ is measurable and bounded with compact support (from other thread) , but that's not the case here.
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Did you try a proof by contradiction? Assume $f$ is not almost everywhere $0$ and is continuous ...

Comment: @quarague Well I did tried but didnt achived any success doing so...

Comment: Sounds like Baire theorem might do the trick

Comment: @tommy1996q  could you show how?

Comment: Are you aware of the Radon transform,   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform  ?

Comment: @user2323232: What is the "other thread"? And what do you mean by $l = 1_{B(x,r)}$ given that $l$ is a line while $1_{B(x,r)}$ is a function?

Comment: @AlexM. I assume OP means that [$\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)dy = 0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^2, r > 0$] implies [$f = 0$ a.e.]. This implication is immediate from the lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you pose is the weak version of a classical result in harmonic analysis, which does not require the continuity nor the compactness of the support of the datum $f$: in order to prove this stronger result, first note that
$$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\Bbb R} f\big(l(t)\big)\mathrm{d}t=0\:\text{ for every}&\text{ straight line } l\subsetneq\Bbb R^2\label{1}\tag{1}\\
\Updownarrow&\\
\int\limits_{\sigma(l_0)} f(l)\,\mathrm{d}l=0\:\text{ for every rigid }&\text{motion }\sigma\in\mathsf{Aut}(\Bbb R^2)\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where by *rigid motion* we mean a bijection of $\Bbb R^2$ in itself which is the composition of a rotation and a translation and $l_0\subsetneq\Bbb R^2$ is a given straight line: this is obvious, since substituting a dilatation of a given straight line $l$ in \eqref{1} does not change the value of the integral, thus these linear transformations do not contribute to it and it is not necessary to consider them.
Now we can state and prove the following:

**Theorem (Cramér & Wald, Newman, Besicovitch)**. If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^2)$ is such that, for an arbitrarily given straight line $l_0\subsetneq\Bbb R^2$, equation \eqref{2} holds, then $f\equiv 0$ a.e..
**Proof**. Let $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)\neq 0$ so that $\Vert \xi\Vert\neq0$ and define $(x,y) \mapsto \sigma_{\Vert \xi\Vert}(x,y)=(u,v)$ as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\xi_1}{\Vert \xi\Vert}& \frac{\xi_2}{\Vert \xi\Vert}\\
-\frac{\xi_2}{\Vert \xi\Vert}& \frac{\xi_1}{\Vert \xi\Vert}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}\quad\forall (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2
$$
The Jacobian of $\sigma_{\Vert \xi\Vert}$ is equal to one therefore, by applying the Fourier transform to $f$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\hat{f}(\xi)&=\iint\limits_{\Bbb R^2} e^{-i\langle\xi,(x,y)\rangle}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int\limits_{\Bbb R} e^{-i\Vert\xi\Vert u} \left[\,\int\limits_{\Bbb R}f\big(\sigma_{\Vert \xi\Vert}^{-1}(u,v)\big)\,\mathrm{d}v\right] \mathrm{d}u=0
\end{split}
$$
since the integral inside the square brackets in the right side of the above equality is equal to \eqref{2} for some $\sigma=\sigma_{\Vert \xi\Vert}(u,\cdot)$. By the arbitrariness of $\xi\in\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, $f\equiv 0$ a.e.. $\blacksquare$

**Final notes**

- When I saw the question and the comment by Christian Blatter, I though this was a classical problem for the Radon transform. However, I saw the comment of mathworker21, I remembered a counterexample and the fact that this is in reality a result related to the Pompeiu problem: I found the above simple and beautiful theorem in reference [1] (Theorem 1, p. 26) while looking for that example.
- Finally, *Chakalov's example* ([1], p. 27) *shows that disks have not the Pompeiu property*, i.e. there exists (even very smooth) functions $f$ such that, for many (even infinitely many) $r>0$,
  $$
  \int\limits_{B(x_0,r)} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=0\quad \forall x_0\in\Bbb R^2,\;  \text{ does not imply }f\equiv 0\, \text{a.e.}
  $$
  where $x_0=(x_{0,1},x_{0,2})$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ are points in $\Bbb R^2$.
  **Edit**. Following the comment of mathworker21, I checked Chakalov's example as reported in [1], and I found that integral formula (2) in the paper is flawed by typos. The correct one is given by Garofalo and Segala in [2], p. 137, and for the completeness I report it here. If we choose $f(x,y)=\sin(ax)$, $a>0$ then we have
  $$
  \int\limits_{B(x_0,r)} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\frac{2\pi r}{a}\sin(ax_{0,1})J_1(ar)
  $$
  where $J_1$ is the first kind Bessel function of order $1$. Choosing $a$ such that $ar$ is a zero of $J_1$ makes the above integral zero for any $x_0\in\Bbb R^2$. Note that the example works also in dimension $n>2$, for the higher dimensional analogue of the Pompeiu problem.

**References**

[1] Nicola Garofalo (1989), "[A new result on the Pompeiu problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwihwsi6_7njAhUKsaQKHQQJBHQQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seminariomatematico.unito.it%2Frendiconti%2Fcartaceo%2F47-3%2F25.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1UhOoa6ZLtacWktd3UnkTw)", 
Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico, Torino, Fascicolo Speciale "PDE and Geometry", vol. 46, 25-38 (1989), [MR1086204](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1086204), [Zbl 0737.35145](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0737.35145)

[2] Nicola Garofalo and Fausto Segala (1994), "[Univalent functions and the Pompeiu problem](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1994-1250819-4)", Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 346, 137-146, [MR1250819](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1250819), [Zbl 0823.30027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0823.30027).

Comment: 1). $||\xi|| \not = 0$. 2). mathworker21. 3). I'm confused by the Chakalov example. What is wrong with the following argument. For a.e. $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $0 = \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{r}\int_{B(x_0,r)} f(y)dy = f(x_0)$.

Comment: The keystone is that even if $\int_{B(x_0,r)}f(y)dy$ for infinitely many $r>0$, the limit for $r\to0$ of the quotient of the integral respect to the area of $B(x_0,r)$ is not necessarily zero. As you see from [the limiting form of $J_0(x)$ for $x=0$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7), $$\begin{split}\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_{B(x_0,r)}f(y)dy &= \lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\frac{2\pi r}{a}\sin(ax_{0,1})J_1(ar) \\ &= \lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\frac{2\pi r}{a}\sin(ax_{0,1})\frac{1}{2}ar=\sin(ax_{0,1}).\end{split}$$ Note that the formula in ref. [1] is flawed by typos.

Comment: Ohhh, is the "for all" just being applied to $x_0$ and not $r$?? I.e., you have some function $f$ and some $r > 0$ such that for all $x_0$, $\int_{B(x_0,r)} f(y)dy = 0$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Exactly: you have infinitely many $r>0$ for which the integral is $0$, corresponding to the zeros of $J_1$. However, $\int_{B(x_0,r)} f(y)dy$ *is not zero for all* $r\>0$, and this is the essence of Chakalov's example (I apologize for the later in my reply, but I just had lunch :)).

Comment: No problem :). I think you should rewrite $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2, r > 0$, since it appears like you're implicitly also saying $\forall r > 0$.

Comment: I just read through everything. Very nice! Can you provide some intuition for the fourier proof? It seems like magic... What is this change of variables really doing? I mean, I see how it replaces the phase by a single variable so we can just integrate over $f$,... but I'm missing the big picture. The theme of fourier analysis is representing functions by waves, so I am just confused how this helps with lines. Sorry if this is too vague.

Comment: @mathworker21 in reality it is nothing special (and I think it is this conceptual simplicity its amazing part): you apply a linear change of variable to the Fourier integral and then apply Fubini-Tonelli in order to evaluate the contribution to the integral by a given linear slice (there emerges a contact with tomography and Radon transform): this is zero, and thus the whole integral is zero. However, if you think I should explain this point, I would add a point to the "**Notes**" section: let me know what do you think.

Comment: Sorry, what I said (and deleted) was extremely stupid. The Fubini-Tonelli is very simple here. I guess I just don't fully understand what a wave means in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The phase is constant along lines....

Comment: @mathworker21 you are putting forward a number of interesting points. I definitely think I should expand them and further improve my answer above, adding something to the **Notes**. I'll figure out how to do so: and thank you for helping me understand how to write a "nice answer".

Comment: Actually, I would prefer they weren't taken. Feel free to write your own thoughts on the matter and I'd be happy to read them :)

Comment: @mathworker21, I have written some notes on the theorem and its proof, available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqqq6ny7j320e52/2019-08-23_Cramer_%26_Wald-Newman-Besicovitch_theorem.pdf?dl=0) to you and all those who want to have a look at them (unfortunately, I do not have reestablished my blog yet). If you'll have a look at them, I'd like to know your opinion, whatever it will be. Best,

Comment: Thanks for this! I've just done a preliminary read, and it looks nice! However, I'm confused about some things. It seems you've proven uniqueness of the fourier transform for functions on $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$, right? It seems that I've deleted some of my previous comments, but the main thing I was trying to understand was the uniqueness of the fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can represent any reasonable $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ as a combination of functions that are constant along lines. *That* was the most magical thing to me. I think it is very intuitive/

Comment: obvious that once you have that magical fact, the problem is solved. Though, you wrote up nicely how one would arrive at the solution from that fact, nicely motivated. However, I want to understand the magical fact better. I think that's where everything lies. And the fact really belongs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of course. If you can adapt your proof that $\hat{f} \equiv 0 \implies f \equiv 0$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, I'd be appreciative. I do hope you agree with me that the ability to express anything as a combination of functions that are constant along lines is what is really going on here...

Comment: @mathworker21 I'll surely do as this is the most natural way to proceed: the reason I have chosen to write down only a $1$-dimensional proof is that this is the route followed by Kolmogorov and Fomin and I choose to follow it since it was the quickest way to write down something. The only really needed step in producing a $n$-dimensional proof, $n\in\Bbb N\setminus \{0\}$, is to generalize lemma 1 in the notes I shared, and I'll have a look at it as soon as possible: obviously, you will be informed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(p)\neq 0$, then WLOG (by replacing $f$ by $-f$ if necessary) we might assume $f(p)>0$. But then by continuity of $f$ there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>f(p)/2$ for all $x$ with $\|x-p\|\leq\varepsilon$, which then gives that the integral of $f$ over every line contained in $B(p,\varepsilon)$ is strictly positive, contradiction.

Comment: I think OP wanted infinite lines.